# PHP : array_intersect not giving expected result

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I am trying to count the matches between `expected` and `actual` in a PHP array, I have this...

```
$array = array(
    "item" => array(
        'expected' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 4,
            '3' => 4,
        ),
        'color' => 'red',
        'actual' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 4,
            '3' => 3,
        ),
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $key => $arrayItem) {

    $matches = array (
        'matches'  => count ( array_intersect ( $arrayItem['expected'], $arrayItem['actual'] ) ),
    );

}

echo "Matches = " . $matches['matches'];
```

I am expecting this to return `2` but it is actually returning `3`. If I change the values like in the example below then it does work...

```
$array = array(
    "item" => array(
        'expected' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 84,
            '3' => 4,
        ),
        'color' => 'red',
        'actual' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 84,
            '3' => 3,
        ),
    ),
);

foreach ($array as $key => $arrayItem) {

    $matches = array (
        'matches'  => count ( array_intersect ( $arrayItem['expected'], $arrayItem['actual'] ) ),
    );

}

echo "Matches = " . $matches['matches'];
```

Anyone any ideas why the top version is not giving me the expected result?

Comment: In first approach, it matches 2nd `4` of `expected`  with 2nd `4` of `actual`.

Comment: From the manual: `array_intersect`: "Returns an array containing all of the values in array1 whose values exist in all of the parameters. "

Comment: Perhaps you want `array_intersect_assoc`?

Comment: I think array_intersect_assoc might be the answer to this one. Reading up on it now

Answer (score 3):

Because it **returns** an array containing all **values in array1** whose values exist in all of the parameters.

`array_intersect(array $array1, array $array2[, array $... ]): array`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Maybe you can see it clearly from this perspective:

```
var_dump(array_intersect([25, 4, 4, 4], [25, 4, 3])); // [25, 4, 4, 4] 
// because the number `4` is in the second array!

var_dump(array_intersect([25, 4, 3], [25, 4, 4, 4])); // [25, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

### The count is actually correct.

It doesn't happen in your second example because you use the numbers 84 and 4, but essentially here are the matches:

`$arrayItem['expected'][1]` matches with `$arrayItem['actual'][1]` (**25** and **25**)

`$arrayItem['expected'][2]` matches with `$arrayItem['actual'][2]` (**4** and **4**)

`$arrayItem['expected'][3]` matches with `$arrayItem['actual'][2]` (**4** and **4**)

The count of 3 is correct.

---

**You can test this by changing your code to the following:**

```
$matches = array(
    'matches' => array_intersect ($arrayItem['expected'], $arrayItem['actual'])
);

var_dump($matches);
```

**Here you'll see this output:**

```
array(1) {
    ["matches"] => array(3) {
        [1]=> int(25) 
        [2]=> int(4) 
        [3]=> int(4)
    }
}
```

Comment: _$arrayItem['expected'][2] and $arrayItem['expected'][3] are counting as a match_ Not true.  [See demo](https://3v4l.org/8JjHO)

Comment: Number `4` is met __twice__ in `expected`, that's why `4` is __checked__ twice in `actual` and gets a match of course. __Nothing is matched with itself__.

Answer (score -1):

it returns 2

```
<?php

 $array = array(
    "item" => array(
        'expected' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 84,
            '3' => 4,
        ),
        'color' => 'red',
        'actual' => array(
            '1' => 25,
            '2' => 84,
            '3' => 3,
        ),
    ),
);

echo count(array_intersect($array['item']['expected'],$array['item']['actual']));
```

Comment: OP knows this already. His question is why `3` for first approach.